# JavaFX - get scene coordinates of child in ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I'm trying to calculate the scene coordinates from a child inside a `ScrollPane`. We did this on several other nodes in our project with this method

```
this.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) ->
{
     final Bounds boundsOnScene = this.localToScene( newValue );
     ..
} );
```

It is really straightforward but how can I calculate the coordinates of the children in a `ScrollPane` even when the specific node is currently out of the view bounds? Our FXML structure looks like this

```xml
<ScrollPane>
   <VBox>
      <Pane/>
      <Pane/>
      <Pane/>
   </VBox>
</ScrollPane>
```

I've searched a while now on the internet but I can not figure out where I should start. Maybe someone could guide me in the right direction?

---

**Edit**: thanks to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176472/javafx-get-scene-coordinates-of-child-in-scrollpane?noredirect=1#comment81303540_47176472) of James_D I figured out what was missing. In a `ScrollPane` the `boundsInLocalProperty` listener will not be invoked during scrolling, so I had to add

```
this.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) ->
{
     final Bounds boundsOnScene = this.localToScene( this.getBoundsInLocal() );
     ...
} );
```

to take the scrolling behavior into account.

Comment: Your calculation looks right, but `boundsInLocal` will not change when the user scrolls, so the listener won't be invoked and you won't recompute the scene bounds. Try adding a listener to the `localToSceneTransformProperty`

Comment: Omg, thank you. I spent almost the whole day yesterday figuring out how can I bind to the scroll event to recalculate the bounds. I thought I would have to subtract the offset by myself. I didn't expect that it is that simple. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Stumbled across this old question, maybe you could add your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) I figured out what was going wrong.

The `boundsInLocal` will not change when the user scrolls. I also needed to listen to the `localToSceneTransformProperty` to recompute the scene bounds.